# Сокеты. Android. Java

Tags: java, android, сокет, клиент-сервер

Решил я соединить сервер с Android приложением. Ввел нужный порт: 7777, ip: 127.0.0.1  и нажал запуститься, но сервер клиента не видит.

Вот код приложения:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int sPort = 7777;
    String ip =  "127.0.0.1";
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.button) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                textView.setText("Server off");
                                InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                                Socket socket = new Socket(ip, sPort);
                                textView.setText("Connected");

                                InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
                                OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

                                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
                                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);


                            } catch (Exception x) {
                                x.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            }
        };
button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: а сервер запущен там же, на Android-устройстве?

Comment: Сервер запущен в консоли, я предварительно написал его в блокноте. Клиент включен на эмуляторе Android Studio.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - это loopback адрес устройства внутри эмулятора. Адрес вашего компьютера в сети "компьютер ⇔ эмулятор" - 10.0.2.2

Comment: @Nofate, Спасибо Вам большое, долго не мог разобраться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/emulator.html).

Каждый экземпляр эмулятора имеет внутренне изолированное сетевое адресное пространство `10.0.2/24` за виртуальным роутером. В сети назначены следующие адреса:

- `10.0.2.1` - Основной шлюз.
- `10.0.2.2` - Специальный псевдоним для вашего loopback-интерфейса на основной машине вне эмулятора (`127.0.0.1` вашего компьютера).
- `10.0.2.3` - Основной DNS-сервер.
- `10.0.2.4` / `10.0.2.5` / `10.0.2.6` - Опциональные дополнительные DNS-сервера.
- `10.0.2.15` - Адрес эмулируемого устройства внутри сети эмулятора.
- `127.0.0.1` - loopback-интерфейс эмулируемого устройства внутри сети эмулятора.